# How to change button Image like toggle button RecyclerView button click programmatically

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-button

I have a `RecyclerView` that is populated with `ListView`. On each of the `ListView` there is a `Button`, which up add the list.

**Here is what the button looks when it is not pressed**

[image]

**Here is what the button looks when it is pressed,**

[image]

How can I keep the buttons pressed respectfully for each `ListView`?

**This is my Adapter**

```
  public class BuildCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BuildCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;
    private List<Build> buildList;
    private List<Build> buildListCopy;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.build_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,  int position) {

       Build build = buildList.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(build.getImages());
        holder.name.setText(build.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return buildList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView name;
        public Button button;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPerson);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPersonName);
            button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addbn);

        }
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {


            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    List<Build> filterList = new ArrayList<Build>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < buildList.size(); i++) {
                        if ((buildList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                                .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                            Build builddata = new Build(buildList.get(i).getImages(), buildList.get(i).getName());

                            filterList.add(builddata);
                        }
                    }
                    results.count = filterList.size();
                    results.values = filterList;

                } else {
                    results.count = buildList.size();
                    results.values = buildList;
                }
                return results;
            }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {

            buildList = (ArrayList<Build>) results.values;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }


    public BuildCustomAdapter(List<Build> buildList) {
        this.buildList = buildList;
    }


}
```

**Build.class**

```
public class Build {
    private String name;
    private int images;

    public Build(int images, String name) {
        this.images = images;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be better if you use *selected* as boolean variable into your pojo class, it will help adapter to set the image according to state. Actually , whenever you scroll-up and down un-visible items remove from the memory, and we have updated our list according to the button event, so second time it will fetch the desired state and again show the previous state image.

**BuildCustomAdapter** *pass context always whenever you create an Adapter, context will help you*

```
 Context context;
    public BuildCustomAdapter(List<Build> buildList,Context context) {
            this.buildList = buildList;
            this.context = context;
        }
```

**Build.java**

```
public class Build {
        private String name;
        private int images;
        private boolean selected;

        public Build(boolean selected, String name,int images) {
            this.images = images;
           this.selected=selected; 
           this.name = name;
        }

        public int getImages() {
            return images;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setSeleted(boolean selected){
            this.selected=selected;
        }

        public boolean isSelected(){
            return selected;
        } 
    }
```

**YourAdapter**

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,  int position) {

            Build build = buildList.get(position);

            holder.imageView.setImageResources(build.getImages());

            holder.name.setText(build.getName());
            setImageIntoButton(holder.button,build.isSelected());

            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        build.setSelected(!build.isSelected());
                        setImageIntoButton(holder.button,build.isSelected());
                    }
                });
        }

      private void setImageIntoButton(Button buttonView,boolean isSelected){
         if(isSelected)
           buttonView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clicked_image); 
            else 
          buttonView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross_image); 
 }
```

**ItemFilter**
change this statement

```
Build builddata = new Build(buildList.get(i).isSelected(), buildList.get(i).getName(),buildList.get(i).getImages());
```

Comment: go through this code, you no need to use  ```build = new Build(R.drawable.ak, "Aksahy Kumar");```

Comment: Hi Abdul Rizwan in my case i have not put `
        public Build(boolean selected, String name) {
            //this.images = images;
           this.selected=selected; 
           this.name = name;
        }`  in activity class ` build = new Build(R.drawable.ak, "Aksahy Kumar");
        buildList.add(build);`

Comment: can you put your activity code. what exactly you wanted to do? first you check code and flow if you will get difficulties then let me know.

Comment: if you are creating an object and putting into list from your activity then pass like ```Build(null,"alok kumar");``` it will work, first parameter I am passing as null so by default it will make boolean as false. so according to false, adapter will set crossImage into imageView. I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have try this code but error Error:(96, 43) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean in activity class and error  build = new Build(R.drawable.ps, "Pramukh Swami");

Comment: do like this ```build = new Build(null, "Pramukh Swami");``` or ```build = new Build(false, "Pramukh Swami");```

Comment: but i have display the multiple image in drawable so i have not put null

Comment: ohhh sorry you wanted button image as toggle image right? if yes give me some time to update this code.

Comment: Right @Abdul Rizwam

Comment: @JaydeepDhamecha I have updated code, please have a look.

Comment: Hi @Abdul Rizam one prob in this case i have already define the add button image in the recycler view layout so all list are show the add button  that add button click so this time change button image so help me plzz

Comment: remove that button image from xml

Comment: In this case user first time show the layout this time not show the button image click the button in left side this time change the button image

Comment: I have already display the button image in open the app and after click the button this time change the button image like selected any solution for this?@Abdul Rizwan

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/addbn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/add_button_icon"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"/>

Answer (score 0):

Check this to give your drawable a state (selected, activated, etc.):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Also, ListView has a choiceMode that you can use.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode

Answer (score 0):

Go to you layout `R.layout.build_list_row` and set background to the button you want to perform this operation and using selector drawable and set your plus and tick image like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tick" android:state_selected="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_plus" />
    </selector>
```

Comment: This method is suitable but i have make programmatically!

Comment: In your scenario setting selector with xml is consider as a best approach..but if want to toggle programmatically than you can performs using if else condition which i will not suggest